# Remove selection in ListBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

We use Caliburn Micro.
I need change color of item after mouseDoubleClick.

A do it like this:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AnswerStatus, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkSeaGreen"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AnswerStatus, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="2">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="IndianRed"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="cal:Message.Attach" Value="[Event MouseDoubleClick] = [Action AnswerDoubleClick($dataContext)]"/>
  </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

But now after double click, color changed but it's hided under selection, and for see color, is needed click on other item.

How remove selection?

Comment: I try bind Selectedindex to ViewModel and set it -1 on doubleClick but it didn't help...

Comment: Just give your custom data template for items

Answer (score 0):

Use an ItemsControl instead of a Listbox. An ItemsControl does not support selection.

Comment: But I need select items from list, i want only remove selection style after double click

Comment: or remove selection after double click.

Comment: How it's work now. Hided by selection:https://imgur.com/9I4H5Ox When single click on other item https://imgur.com/qTAK42x

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with caliburn.micro, so the below is generic wpf/xaml.

If you define your listbox in xaml as:

```
  <ListBox Name="TheList" MouseDoubleClick="TheList_MouseDoubleClick" DisplayMemberPath="AsString">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AnswerStatus, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkSeaGreen"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
          </DataTrigger>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AnswerStatus, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="2">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="IndianRed"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
          </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>

      </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  </ListBox>
```

With the MouseDoubleClick handler defined as:

```
private void TheList_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
  {
    MyItem item = TheList.SelectedItem as MyItem;
    if (item != null)
    {
      item.SwapStatus();
      TheList.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
  }
}
```

And your listbox item view model is :

```
  public class MyItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    private int m_value;
    public int Value
    {
      get { return m_value; }
      set
      {
        m_value = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Value");
        OnPropertyChanged("AsString");
      }
    }

    public string AsString
    {
      get
      {
        return ToString();
      }
    }

    private int m_answerStatus;
    public int AnswerStatus
    {
      get { return m_answerStatus; }
      set
      {
        m_answerStatus = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("AnswerStatus");
        OnPropertyChanged("AsString");
      }
    }

    public void SwapStatus()
    {
      AnswerStatus = m_answerStatus == 1 ? 2 : 1;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
      return $"MyItem: {Value} {AnswerStatus}";
    }
  }
```

(`TheList.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(i => new MyItem { Value = i, AnswerStatus = i % 2 + 1 });`
)

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me. 
in the Listbox resources bind the`IsSelected`property:

```
<ListBox.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
         <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
     </Style>
</ListBox.Resources>
```

now just set it that item to `IsSelected = false` wherever you need, and you should be all set. 
In my case, I needed a list that once the number of selected items reaches a certain predefined number, it won't let you choose any more items. Therefore in my case, in the `SelectChanged` event handler i set the condition, which essentially disallowed an further selections by setting the selected item's IsSelected back to false if the condition isn't satisfied.